# How to change options in two selects with same id?

Tags: jquery, select

I have number of selects on my page and due to design I need to double selected options in each two of them.

Here is how my html looks like

```
<div class="">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="first">Dummy text 1</label>
    <select id="first">
      <option>1</option>
      <option>2</option>
      <option>3</option>
      <option>4</option>
      <option>5</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="">
  <div class="form-group">
    <select id="first">
      <option>Dummy text 1</option>
      <option>1</option>
      <option>2</option>
      <option>3</option>
      <option>4</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div> 
<div class="">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="second">Dummy text 2</label>
    <select id="second">
      <option>1</option>
      <option>2</option>
      <option>3</option>
      <option>4</option>
      <option>5</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="">
  <div class="form-group">
    <select id="second">
      <option>Dummy text 2</option>
      <option>1</option>
      <option>2</option>
      <option>3</option>
      <option>4</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is example https://jsfiddle.net/tmg0705o/5/

What is correct way to change option in one select with id "first"if it is changed in another select with id "first"? Same with id "second" etc. Is there any way to write one code for all such selects and to highlight everytime all id's?

Comment: Id should  be unique you can use class in this case.instead of matching text you should add value in the options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this generic solution: [jsfiddle.net/bharatsing/tmg0705o/7/](https://jsfiddle.net/bharatsing/tmg0705o/7/)

- You need to give same **select-group** for select elements which are same and need to change.
- Also need to give **mapped** class to all select elements. So it binds click events
- When select element value changed it will trigger change event code and select values for other select elements with same **select-group**.

```js
$(".mapped").change(function(){
   var _value=$(this).val();
   var select_group=$(this).attr("select-group");
   $('select[select-group="'+select_group+'"]').not(this).val(_value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="first">Dummy text 1</label>
    <select id="first" class="mapped" select-group="first">
      <option>1</option>
      <option>2</option>
      <option>3</option>
      <option>4</option>
      <option>5</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="">
  <div class="form-group">
    <select id="first" class="mapped" select-group="first">
      <option>Dummy text 1</option>
      <option>1</option>
      <option>2</option>
      <option>3</option>
      <option>4</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div> 
<div class="">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="second">Dummy text 2</label>
    <select id="second" class="mapped" select-group="second">
      <option>1</option>
      <option>2</option>
      <option>3</option>
      <option>4</option>
      <option>5</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="">
  <div class="form-group">
    <select id="second" class="mapped" select-group="second">
      <option>Dummy text 2</option>
      <option>1</option>
      <option>2</option>
      <option>3</option>
      <option>4</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: works perfect, thank you!    to understand for future how this part works? ` $('select[select-group="'+select_group+'"]').not(this).val(_value);`

Comment: You need to give same `select-group` for select elements which are same and need to change. Then this will find selected select element group and according to it find other select elements and change value of those select elements.